# SQL Server 2014 sa account audit trail

Tags: sql-server, auditing, audit-trail, sa

I need to implement an auditing for everyone logging in to SQL Server 2014 using the `sa` account. User should be able to provide user id and reason why he/she is logging as `sa`, which should be stored in a specific table with a timestamp.

What is the best way to do this? What language/techniques I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers

Comment: Whatever you store in this table... it can be deleted by sa. You shouldn't be letting people log in as sa at all

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use windows authentication. _Don't hand out the sa password!_

Comment: Thanks for the advises! My manager suggested to use Perl or Python. I'm new to coding so no idea where to start..

Comment: Your manager doesn't have a clue. How on earth could you possibly use Perl to enforce auditing in a database? You can't. No matter what you use to write to this audit table, someone with the `sa` password can just log in and delete or edit audit entries. I don't know what you're trying to solve, but if you've handed out the sa password, you need to change the password, then take a step back and look at your security.

Comment: The 'proper' way to implement login auditing is to use serve audits https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-setup-and-use-sql-server-audit-feature/ but again, any sa user can just turn them off and alter them.

Comment: I implemented it =) If you would like you can watch the video by link https://youtu.be/7GWz_YW1teI